# Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе букв в age был отрицательный ответ

Tags: python

```
age = input('Здравствуй! Сколько тебе лет?\n')

if age < str(18):
    print('Тебе меньше 18\n')

elif age >= str(18):
    print('Тебе больше 18')
```

## Что нужно написать?

```
elif age != ??  
    print('Я не знаю такого числа')`
```

Comment: `if not age.isdigit(): ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
age = input('Enter age: ')

try:
    age = int(age)

    if age < 18:
        print('Your age is smaller than 18')
    else:
        print('Your age is bigger than 18')

except ValueError:
    print('I don`t know this number')
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй поставить фильтр на сам input, а потом обработать исключение(фильтр нарушен):

```
try:
    a = int(input('Сколько тебе лет?'))
except ValueError:
    print('Такие числа мне не ведомы!')
```

В блоке кода try ты пишешь свой код с if/else/elif.